# Python - Getting lyrics back from musixmatch json response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, musixmatch

In Python, I'm trying to parse the json response from musixmatch api but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the information given, please help!
I can post the JSON Response later if necessary but it is quite a bit of text.

```
import json
from os.path json, dirname
from musixmatch import Musixmatch

musixmatch = Musixmatch(<api key>)

lyrics = musixmatch.matcher_lyrics_get('Grenade', 'Bruno Mars')


print (lyrics)

for item in jsonLyric['message']:
   for thing in item['body']:
     for stuff in thing['lyrics']:
        print(stuff['lyrics_body'])
```

This is the output that I'm getting back with the print(lyrics)

```
{"message": {"header": {"status_code": 200, "execute_time": 0.005511999130249}, "body": {"lyrics": {"lyrics_id": 14678126, "can_edit": 0, "locked": 1, "published_status": 3, "action_requested": "", "verified": 0, "restricted": 0, "instrumental": 0, "explicit": 0, "lyrics_body": "Easy come, easy go, that's just how you live oh\nTake, take, take it all, but you never give\nShould have known you was trouble from the first kiss\nHad your eyes wide open,\nWhy were they open?\n\nGave you all I had and you tossed it in the trash\nYou tossed it in the trash, you did\nTo give me all your love is all I ever asked 'cause\nWhat you don't understand is I'd catch a grenade for ya (yeah, yeah)\nThrow my head on a blade for ya (yeah, yeah)\nI'd jump in front of a train for ya (yeah, yeah)\nYou know I'd do anything for ya (yeah, yeah)\n\nOh oh, I would go through all this pain\nTake a bullet straight through my brain\nYes, I would die for ya baby\nBut you won't do the same\n\nNo, no, no, no\n...\n\n******* This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use *******", "lyrics_language": "en", "lyrics_language_description": "English", "script_tracking_url": "https://tracking.musixmatch.com/t1.0/m_js/e_1/sn_0/l_14678126/su_0/rs_0/tr_3vUCALM0_W22leSuW0j51mdZjjfpE4x6a9jOCvWJRkoOBKyShPRRZQELOwGOsZtDZ8P7rI_Ugft_vMQta6YUky74d5X3RIpnkF1GkipbfBPqaDh2M9h4wtFKqwGgJoy8k52jf0kTKu2GFboxJpmcZP_TL17Tt5-rkmsIOB4VQk1LX_s66Du-rGVtu_NcuDuzquhrpHnIEyygjxJGcHYfbpHfFt3gDfDkAfuv25OHWoHt6FJarcoSeY5eloAlMJtqtQqXVIU4bVp3zmqnTdEsjj5mvyBOq2Yvl_WRsRYBiSP4fISEiW8Nz_cwKdLFqVo-9L4Pcz7ryASfVXfRD-nROD18LJIBomN5JzzcPMk9hEjHwmxt9PUccK5e_G23RYrgXgrWJlVQUyoIX5CNb_3IW893C0xfSrEm/", "pixel_tracking_url": "https://tracking.musixmatch.com/t1.0/m_img/e_1/sn_0/l_14678126/su_0/rs_0/tr_3vUCAB0Xj7CAyD4mjojoI5pSqo0L_Qojn7Q9jhh7eIMnru0DnnnxducKM9BTbyEX19XGYKgaLEjaRJUedry3aKHTl45sXeTudU6Y5g6DYg4UqxqUZVQuGT8RofGA25JeQfvfJnabBr4Ua2rDhu52CH9gY5T4MO58sTV_WEnz1OeovHSJJrcR7FJ6dGtZ7ddBSj5DAs3tXvKVZM-CMngsa4lVHgJvlKyQBI9dIlKpIasxUiHE8ESQ5nvq355A-9hB38ZO1xBSBE_poFKeFODVuxAYwt61nwkcy1INwNyRfu-88W0T8qdzmNdHPzC3CZ13W6_zvJQs144ir8AMF_ScjfXdyIZ5rBKT3yQYp4BIAuWYALrfv87mitBdkqukq_HiN79vaqsKTpn2dr5-IMe97ioMeI4xHwX2/", "html_tracking_url": "https://tracking.musixmatch.com/t1.0/m_html/e_1/sn_0/l_14678126/su_0/rs_0/tr_3vUCANQr9qsfeDL9iPgGrXIvJIBLLsgir3pFRzL4BslntB9GYllG57LNZuNC08A5g3r87JYVDgKTKk4QfYdU-j3sfs8i8onqzpCCV_w27R7ePS_k13wHNHBfSZpHQcJL4ocPj9i9E-Cms8yT9q4vLC31c3DGfudXXV6k5MajtdCVZdHaHfeNNm6tmstseeFCD6MuQxmRRkiUmHYTfgi2TfPwR4CzOZbEdULg5X6AHiiT4MMfIKAspZwghHUMhq3udos-8052sIMMUyB8nQrquajI8ZyZGX9UzKQi21ZDfyFz5fyUF9gYwzX4WA1gxhmVlsppG_-ocY7m29ddOUjEcg0HM0b7CsrJw8tAtcnwLnFovDcW-a7xzNUDlCkqXBLU_sDVg_na0uE4fH1QuYFKvwX5bwlQ1d-l/", "lyrics_copyright": "Lyrics powered by www.musixmatch.com. This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use and only 30% of the lyrics are returned.", "writer_list": [], "publisher_list": [], "backlink_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Bruno-Mars/Grenade?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=", "updated_time": "2016-03-18T14:38:56Z"}}}}
```

Comment: what is your output, what is the expected output? knowing what the JSON response is would also help

Comment: Posted the output that I'm trying to parse. I believe its JSON based on how its structured but I could be wrong

Comment: what is the expected output? what is `jsonLyric`? why not just do `lyrics['message']['body']['lyrics']['lyrics_body']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as can be seen the JSON response is a dictionary, it has many other dictionaries inside of it but the one we want to reach it is the body dictionary which contains the "lyrics_body" and its value.

How could we do this? Well it's actually quite simple. In one line we could just keep calling the dictionary and pass the key which contains another key, so for instance the first dictionary we want to access is the whole JSON response so we could call the lyrics variable, which contains the JSON response, and then we pass the key we want to access in this case "message", lyrics["message"].

```
print(lyrics["message"]["body"]["lyrics"]["lyrics_body"])
```

The way you were doing it was also very simple. You just want to iterate through every single key in the integrated dictionaries.

```
for message in lyrics:
    for body in lyrics[message]:
     if body == "body":
         for lyric in lyrics[message][body]:
             for lyrBod in lyrics[message][body][lyric]:
                 if lyrBod == "lyrics_body":
                     print(lyrics[message][body][lyric][lyrBod])
```

As you can see it's the same thing but just takes longer.

Hope this helps